# sanitize HTML style tag in java to prevent javascript injection from WYSIWYG

Tags: java, security, xss, wysiwyg

There are known XSS attacks like:

```
<DIV STYLE="color: red; width: expression(alert('XSS')); background-image: url('expression.png') ">
```

Or

```
<DIV STYLE="background-image: url(javascript:alert('XSS'));  border-image: url(images/javascript.png) 30 round round;">
```

Or

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="1; URL=javascript:alert(/xxs/.source)">empty
```

And i need to sanitize html to this:

```
<DIV STYLE="color: red; background-image: url('expression.png') ">
```

Or

```
<DIV STYLE="border-image: url(images/javascript.png) 30 round round;">
```

Or

```
empty
```

Is there java library, that provide such protections?

Answer (score 1):

This one for sure: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project

and maybe this one (faster):
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project

Comment: I tried AntiSamy and it is almost work, however i get one very strange behavior of the library. I have created question, but there is no answer yet:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343035
I thnk you can know answer, so asking you directy =D