# antisamy parser force closing tag

Tags: java, security, html-parsing, owasp, antisamy

I use Antisamy for validating HTML. My policy allow iframes, like youtube videos. Problem is - if tag is empty(like this):

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uswzriFIf_k?feature=player_detailpage" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

than after cleaning it will be like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uswzriFIf_k?feature=player_detailpage" allowfullscreen/>
```

But it should have normal closing tag.

And this break all content on page after.
I already set my directives to use most of HTML but not XML:

```
<directives>
    <directive name="omitXmlDeclaration" value="true"/>
    <directive name="omitDoctypeDeclaration" value="true"/>
    <directive name="maxInputSize" value="200000"/>
    <directive name="nofollowAnchors" value="true" />
    <directive name="validateParamAsEmbed" value="true" />
    <directive name="useXHTML" value="false"/>

    <directive name="embedStyleSheets" value="false"/> 
    <directive name="connectionTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <directive name="maxStyleSheetImports" value="3"/>
    <directive name="formatOutput" value="false"/>
</directives>
```

But this not help.

UPD: switching between parsers and playing with directives still did not give any results.

UPD2: this is part of my configuration, responsible for handling `iframe` tag:

```
    <tag name="iframe" action="validate">
        <attribute name="src">
            <regexp-list>
                <regexp name="youtube"/>
                <regexp name="slideshare"/>
            </regexp-list>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="allowfullscreen">
             <regexp-list>
                 <regexp name="anything"/>
             </regexp-list>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="scrolling">
            <regexp-list>
                <regexp name="anything"/>
            </regexp-list>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="marginwidth">
            <regexp-list>
                <regexp name="anything"/>
            </regexp-list>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="marginheight">
            <regexp-list>
                <regexp name="anything"/>
            </regexp-list>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="frameborder">
            <regexp-list>
                <regexp name="anything"/>
            </regexp-list>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="style"/>
    </tag>
```

Any idea?

Comment: I know 4 years have passed.... but by any chance , can you recollect whether you managed to resolve this? Grasping at straws for last two days

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<tag name="iframe" action="validate"/>
```

And add a tag to this list -

```
<allowed-empty-tags>
   <literal-list>
      <literal value="iframe"/>
   </literal-list>
</allowed-empty-tags>
```

See [http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/...](http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/source/browse/Java/antisamy-sample-configs/src/main/resources/antisamy-anythinggoes.xml?spec=svn05665eaf3b59c61c6381c7c45047d10359f16c5e&r=05665eaf3b59c61c6381c7c45047d10359f16c5e)

Comment: This was done. I update my question. Thnks. Problem is - it validate and handle correctly. But if tag has empty body - it is replaced with selfenclosed tag. But some tags (iframe, form, ...) do not work in browser if is selfenclosed.

Comment: same. I already have this. This is responce for allowing selfclosed tag, but have no impact on tag transformation.

Comment: Even more - i already have own type of `AntiSamySAXScanner` and playing with keys: http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/settings.html, but still no result yet.

Comment: I am having the same issue. How did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In my case it was due to the AntiSamy policy having this directive:

```
<directive name="useXHTML" value="true" />
```

Which, per the OWASP documentation, will output the sanitized data in XHTML format as opposed to just regular HTML. 
Please see:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AntiSamy_Directives

Changing that value to false will allow the sanitized output to be provided as valid HTML. Block level elements will not be shortened and become invalid markup.